# Linux commands in Alpine docker image +755 invalid mode

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am building a Docker image using the Node:12 base image. I am trying to switch it to use Node:12-alpine instead due to the smaller image size. I have installed bash and shadow in Alpine to be able to run `chmod` commands.

I am running into an error with one of the RUN commands `RUN chmod +755`. The error message: `chmod: invalid mode '+755'`

Note that this works using the Node:12 base image, so I think I just need to install another package in Alpine linux? Thanks!

```
FROM node:12.8-alpine

# Create working directory
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /home/node/app

# Install bash and shadow for permissions chmod commands
RUN apk add --no-cache bash && apk add shadow

# Add `/home/node/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /home/node/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Copy code
COPY --chown=node . /home/node/app

# Update umask
RUN chmod +755 /home/node/app/entrypoint.sh && \
    echo 'umask 002' >> /home/node/.profile && \
    echo 'umask 002' >> /home/node/.bashrc && \
    npm install

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: +755? what does the + represent? I know what the numbers are but that + is a mystery to me

Comment: + means add this permission to the other permissions that the file already has.

Comment: `+` is used with `w r g u ..` but I don't think that it works with the numbers. Check the [man](https://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html)

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel Hmm, good to know. I actually didn't write that part of the script, and it does work on the node:12 base image (just not in Alpine).

Comment: The Alpine image uses `chmod` from the `busybox` project which is likely different from whichever `chmod` you use on your other image.  The `busybox` chmod is very striped down and likely does not process the erroneous syntax of putting a `+` in front of numerical permissions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The various Alpine-based Docker images use a minimal toolset called [BusyBox](https://busybox.net/), which tends to only implement the functionality required in standard utilities and no more.  In particular, [the POSIX.1 definition of `chmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html#tag_20_17) specifies (emphasis mine):

> The *mode* operand shall be **either** a *symbolic_mode* expression or a non-negative octal integer.

So according to the standard, you can either use the `+rwx` form to add bits, or the octal `0755` form to specify a permission, but not combine the two.

In the context of a Docker image, you're usually dealing with a pretty fixed filesystem layout, and in any case you know what you want the permissions to be; you should be able to run

```
RUN chmod 0755 /home/node/app/entrypoint.sh
```

without installing any additional packages.

(Also note that shell dotfiles usually aren't read by Docker, so the modifications to `.profile` and `.bashrc` have no effect.  Typically you do want your application to be owned by root but executed by a different user, for an additional layer of security to prevent the application files from being unintentionally modified.)