# gitlab ci/cd ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1 on chmod og= $STAGE_ID_RSA

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

This is my ci.yml

```
deploy-stage:
  stage: deploy
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
    - chmod og= $STAGE_ID_RSA
    - apk update && apk add openssh-client
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker stop $CI_PROJECT_NAME || true"
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker rm $CI_PROJECT_NAME || true"
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker image rm $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true"
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY"
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
    - ssh -i $STAGE_ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $STAGE_SERVER_USER@$STAGE_SERVER_IP "docker run -d --restart unless-stopped --name $CI_PROJECT_NAME -p 8882:4000 -e "variableData=Docker-Run-Command" $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
```

I get this error:

```
BusyBox v1.35.0 (2022-05-09 17:27:12 UTC) multi-call binary.
Usage: chmod [-Rcvf] MODE[,MODE]... FILE...
MODE is octal number (bit pattern sstrwxrwxrwx) or [ugoa]{+|-|=}[rwxXst]
    -R  Recurse
    -c  List changed files
    -v  Verbose
    -f  Hide errors
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

And this my variable:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zegmz.png

And I enter breakline end of `STAGE_ID_RSA` value

Answer (score 1):

First, you can use `chmod og= -- $STAGE_ID_RSA` to make sure chmod will *not* consider `$STAGE_ID_RSA` as [an option, but a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309).

Second, `chmod [OPTIONS] [ugoa…][-+=]perms…[,…] FILE...` means the `chmod` applies to a *file*.

If `$STAGE_ID_RSA` represents a *value*, that would not work.
You would need to redirect its content to a file.

Yet, I do see [`STAGE_ID_RSA`](https://github.com/tcallsen/wordpress-gitlab-ci#deployment-ssh-user=) here, used as you do in [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://github.com/tcallsen/wordpress-gitlab-ci/blob/de080c52c121fe63f25a4b6733a158fbf5835784/.gitlab-ci.yml#L11-L15=), *but* using the  `kroniak/ssh-client` rather than `alpine:latest`.

The `chmod` in `alpine:latest` might not behave like a `chmod` in a more traditional image.
See "[Linux commands in Alpine docker image `+755` invalid mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57665989/6309)".
That is most likely your issue.